# Retrofit not working on phone when trying to connect on local server

Tags: android, connection, retrofit2

When trying to connect to a local server from the phone, if I enter the ip address and the port directly in the phone's browser it works, but if I use it in Retrofit, in order to do a get request from the app, the connection is not made. Can someone help me? Why is this happening?

Comment: please show to us what you have tried

Comment: http or https?.

Answer (score 0):

If u are running with emulator use URL as http://10.0.2.2:8080/ instead of localhost

Running from mobile app use PC IP address

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add to manifest file in

> <application ....  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>